# Is there a way to make optional React props types cleaner with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In React, it's common to use `null` to signify that a prop is optional:

```
function Foo({ count = null }) {}
```

The TS type for this would be:

```
function Foo({ count = null }: { count: number | null }): ReactElement {}
```

I think `| null` looks unclean and I'm looking for a better way to do this. One alternative is:

```
function Foo({ count }: { count?: number }): ReactElement {}
```

However, this breaks the React best-practice of specifying default props. I'd have to disable the Eslint `react/require-default-props` rule. It's still obvious to developers which props are optional. The main issue is I'd have to deal with `undefined` more often, e.g. `<Foo count={someCondition ? 123 : undefined} />`.

Is there a better way? Preferably a way to let me keep default props as `null` while keeping the TS types clean?

**Edit:**
Another alternative is nullables:

```
type N<T> = T | null;

function Foo({ count = null }: { count: N<number> }): ReactElement {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will sound a cleaner solution and it may feel like a bit cumbersome you can define your argument type explicitly like below :

```
class FooArg {
  constructor(public count: number | null = null) { } // you define your parameter logic here
// define what is required etc.
}

// and use it like this
function Foo(arg: FooArg): ReactElement {}

// or all optional 
function Boo(arg?: FooArg): ReactElement {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgPAFQHxQLxQVAPlAdgVwBtCBuAKFEigCUIBDAY2AFFCIBbCXYNKAbwC+ZBoToBnMVABiAexkBBAE4BzfmShQGM3GOCL8TGYoAUYfACNCASwaaZ+bgC48+duYiKsBYmm+EAlPxQQkIAZg5MVtrScsahclCOsgoq-s60jCxsnNxBWjoybAB0hDLKcXJFWg7A-iRQihDA+Iq4-AJhEcBRbQBCsfEyAPyJyUrKaTT0TKwcXDx8dgXFpeWDQ1X23HUNTS1tgkJkyca4EADuMSnl-v5k-TLG-kA)